# Como guardar data e hora em uma variável ao clicar em botão

Tags: jquery

Preciso guardar data e hora em uma variável ao clicar em um botão que inicia uma tarefa para posteriormente envia-la para o BD, por exemplo:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="IniciarTarefa" id="acao"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="IniciarTarefa" name="IniciarTarefa" class="btn btn-info">Iniciar Tarefa</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tentei usar esse script mas ficou muito confuso porque não tenho um campo no form e mesmo criando um capo hidden não deu certo.

[Exemplo de Código guardando valor](http://www.criarweb.com/artigos/exemplos/jquery/core/data.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O script que referes guarda informação num campo `data-` dentro de um elemento do DOM. Isso pode facilmente ser adaptado ao teu código e quando precisares desse valor numa variável podes simplesmente ir buscar com `.data('nomeDoCampo')`.

Um exemplo usando o teu HTML, e usando a `div.form-group` para guardar a informação seria:

```
$('#IniciarTarefa').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.form-group').data('inicio', new Date().getTime());
});

$('#mostrar').on('click', function () {
    // esta variável time tem um timestamp que podes enviar para a BD
    var time = $('.form-group').data('inicio'); 
    alert(new Date(time));
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ogn1o10u/

Comment: Olá @Sergio, muito obrigado pela excelente dica e ainda mais por disponibilizar o exemplo, agradeço.

Answer (score 2):

Gostaria de dá uma informação complementar a resposta do @Sergio, então lá vai mais um "comentário resposta".

Vamos supor que no seu `HTML` tenha um elemento com um `data custom attribute (data-*)` semelhante ao seguinte:

```
<div id="helloWorld" data-nome="Hello World!"></div>
```

No jQuery você poderá acessar o valor desta propriedade de duas formas:

```js
var helloWorld = $("#helloWorld");
var usingAttr = helloWorld.attr("data-nome");
var usingData = helloWorld.data("nome");
console.log(usingAttr); //saida: "Hello World!"
console.log(usingData); //saida: "Hello World!"
```

```html
<div id="helloWorld" data-nome="Hello World!" ></div>
```

Porem caso você faça um set usando `.data("nome", value)`, ele irá atualizar o valor apenas no objeto data, porém não irá atualizar o valor do atributo data, como no exemplo abaixo:

```js
var helloWorld = $("#helloWorld");
helloWorld.data("nome", "Hello Mars?");
var usingAttr = helloWorld.attr("data-nome");
var usingData = helloWorld.data("nome");
console.log(usingAttr); //saida: "Hello World!"
console.log(usingData); //saida: "Hello Mars?"
```

```html
<div id="helloWorld" data-nome="Hello World!" ></div>
```

Mas se você fizer um set usando `.attr("data-nome", value)`, então o valor do objeto e do atributo data serão atualizados:

```js
var helloWorld = $("#helloWorld");
helloWorld.attr("data-nome", "Hello Mars?");
var usingAttr = helloWorld.attr("data-nome");
var usingData = helloWorld.data("nome");
console.log(usingAttr); //saida: "Hello Mars?"
console.log(usingData); //saida: "Hello Mars?"
```

```html
<div id="helloWorld" data-nome="Hello World!" ></div>
```

por fim, caso queria acessar uma `data custom attribute (data-*)` que possua um nome composto usando o método `.data()`, você terá que remover os hifens e transformar o nome em pascalCase, porem usando `.attr()` nada muda:

```js
var helloWorld = $("#helloWorld");
var usingAttr = helloWorld.attr("data-nome-completo");
var usingData = helloWorld.data("nomeCompleto"); //Pascal Case
console.log(usingAttr); //saida: "Hello World!"
console.log(usingData); //saida: "Hello World!"
```

```html
<div id="helloWorld" data-nome-completo="Hello World!" ></div>
```

Isto ocorre por que o método `.data()` foi criado antes da especificação dos `data custom attribute (data-*)` e pode ser utilizado para armazenar qual quer tipo de objeto (string, inteiro, float, Date, JSON, etc), enquanto que um atributo pode armazenar apenas texto (string).

Comment: Obrigado @TobyMosque, foi esclarecedor, ainda mais para mim que tenho pouco conhecimento no assunto, valeu as grandes dicas.